# How should you save a jwk?

Tags: authentication, jwt, jwk

I hope this is not a naive question but how should you save a jwk when getting it from a .well-known/jwks.json domain.

Currently I hard code the modulus and exponent but that doesn't seem to be a great solution.

Adding it to a database seems pointless as it would be an unreasonable call because the e & n value wouldn't change.

Storing in cache seems like one of the best solutions.

Making the call to .well-known/jwks.json for every every request just seems unessesary as well.

What is everybody else's way of doing it?

Comment: Which level in the application stack are you talking about? Server, client, ...?

Comment: On the server side.

Answer (score 0):

The storage of a key set you get through a GET call should relies on the HTTP headers and especially the `cache-control` directive.
If `no-cache` or `no-store` are set, then you should not save the key set and get it whenever you need to use it.

In general, you will have a `max-age` directive (e.g. see the [key set from Google](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs)). I recommend you to respect that directive and store the key set in your application cache for that time.

I am not sure that the use of a DB is relevant here ; a cache storage is generally more efficient than a DB one.